# Oracle Table Data to the TXT File

Tags: sql

As the topic says I need to export my table data to the txt file. I did some googling but I couldn't manage to do it. Waiting for your helps.

Comment: There's like a wizard for this that is step by step. How did you not find it? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/impexp.htm#BCEGAFAB

Comment: @JacobH I found this article but didnt think this can solve my problem.

Comment: Use an external table, or do it in sqlplus

Comment: I forgot to say that I am using PL/SQL Developer.